# Is there a way to better format Pandas data frames when printing them in Sublime text?

Tags: pandas, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

When I print out a pandas data frames, it only uses around half of my screen size. Is there a way to adjust this, or maybe have the table open up in a new widnow?

Answer (score 1):

try `pd.set_option('width', 1000)`.

Comment: use pd.reset_option("display.max_rows") to reset the value when needed.